# Magento 2 Changing Base URL breaks pages

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, magento2.2

I tried changing the base url and base secure url together with base path url and secure base path url but upon changing it from `https://test.com/` to `https://test.com/sh/shop` it breaks all the pages in the frontend. Any solution for this? Would really appreaciate any help thanks

Comment: you cannot convert url, to test.com to test.com/sh/shop, as your DNS is pointing to the IP and magento installation at suppose /var/www/html/YOUR_PROJECT so for DNS test.com means YOUR_PROJECT folder.

Comment: @MrunmayDeswandikar what I'm after is to implement a multistore and multiwebsite. So let say I have one main website which is test.com and another website having a url of test.com/web2 I would like it to be accessed using different url. Also note that web2 is already defined in our dns. So I just need to make the CSS and other assets work. From what I've seen all assets cannot be found

Comment: Got you. So you want to create a multi site store. Magento has this feature. You need to create two single store websites in magento admin. 1 will be test.com, 2nd will be test.com/sh/shop.  Check this for details : https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/multi-site/ms_websites.html

Comment: Base urls of both sites will be different, so this will not cause css issue.

Comment: @MrunmayDeswandikar wow thanks for this dude.. Really helpful. Wished I could accept your answer. If you add your answer will gladly accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got you.

So you want to create a multi site store.

**Magento has this feature**. You need to create two single store websites in magento admin.

**1 will be test.com,**

**2nd will be test.com/sh/shop.**

Check this for details : https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/multi-site/ms_websites.html

Base urls of both sites will be different, **so this will not cause css issue**